# Two navbar-inner on the same page how to change the padding of each?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added two bootstrap inner navbar's on the same page. I have created custom css to target my bars. I can change the header navbar's horizontal padding, but when I try to do same for the footer navbar, I am not able to change it. How to change horizontal padding of both navbars on the same page.

Here is my code:

Header Navbar
[image: Image of the code]

Comment: Can you share your CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you prefix your css statements for the footer with `footer`, like so:

```
footer .navbar-inner span {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

that should differentiate between your header and your footer.